# What is the power set of 2^{x,y}?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know that power sets have 2^|A| elements, where |A|=cardinality of the set. Then for 2^{x,y}, it should have 2^2^2 = 16 elements. The elements I know are: {}, 2^{x,y}, 2^{}, 2^{x} and 2^{y}. But I don't know what the remaining 11 elements of the power set could be.

Comment: Are you asking for the power set of $2^{x, y}$?  Because your question is not terribly clear.

Answer (score 2):

So, the elements of $2^{\{x,y\}}$ are:

$$\emptyset, \{x\}, \{y\}, \{x,y\}$$

and then the elements of $\large 2^{2^{\{x,y\}}}$ are (all $16$ of them):

- $0$-element: $\emptyset$,
- $1$-element: $\{\emptyset\}, \{\{x\}\}, \{\{y\}\}, \{\{x,y\}\}$,
- $2$-element: $\{\emptyset,\{x\}\}, \{\emptyset,\{y\}\}, \{\emptyset,\{x,y\}\}, \{\{x\}, \{y\}\}, \{\{x\}, \{x, y\}\}, \{\{y\}, \{x,y\}\}$,
- $3$-element: $\{\emptyset, \{x\}, \{y\}\}, \{\emptyset, \{x\}, \{x,y\}\}, \{\emptyset,\{y\}, \{x,y\}\}, \{\{x\}, \{y\}, \{x,y\}\}$,
- $4$-element: $\{\emptyset, \{x\}, \{y\}, \{x,y\}\}$